I'm trying to build a nand2tetris assembler but the ply.lex library in python keep breaking my assembly instructions to different lines
the first thought I had was that I didn't manage to handle the new line character properly because it keeps throwing the new line character "\n" whenever I try to append the instructions for further processing and I tried different ways to resolve it but still no luck
among the things I tried
-having a dedicated function for handling the new line characters which will be mentioned in the provided code
-adjusting the ignore token
-excluding the new character through the regex
-I tried stripping the new line character from the source code file
I even tried increasing the buffer size feature which the library offered
this is a segment of the output where the problem relies:
\['D=M', 'AD=D-1', '0;jmp', '**MD=1\\nA', 'MD=!D',** 'MD=A-1', 'AMD=D&A', 'MD=D|A', 'AMD=M-d', 'D=m+d', 'MD=-**D\\nD', ';JGT',** 'd=m'\]

PS: the snippets which are BOLD are the ones where the instructions are overlapped
#the original instructions are provided in the source code#
from ply import lex
import termcolor
import re

Ainst_address = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
def if_address(Ainstruct):
      return bool(Ainst_address.match(Ainstruct))

tokens = (
  "LABEL",
  "ADDRESSES",
  "CINSTRUCTION",
  "AINSTRUCTION",
  "COMMENTS"
)

t_LABEL = r'\((?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+)?)*\)'
t_ADDRESSES = r'\@[0-9]+'
t_AINSTRUCTION = r'\@(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+)'
t_CINSTRUCTION = r'[A-Za-z0]{1,3}\s{0,2}(?:[=|;])\s{0,2}(?:(?:!|-)?)\s{0,2}(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})\s{0,2}(?:(?:\||\+|\-|&)?(?:[A-Za-z0-9])?)|;(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3})? '
t_ignore = '\t\r\f\v '  # Ignore whitespace
t_COMMENTS = r'//.*'

lex.lex(debug=0, optimize=False, reflags=re.DOTALL)

def t_NEWLINE(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
    pass
    

def t_error(t):
  print(f"Illegal character '{t.value[0]}' at line {t.lexer.lineno}")
  t.lexer.skip(1)
  

def parse_source_code(source_code):
  #lex.lex(debug=0, optimize=False, reflags=re.DOTALL)
  lexer = lex.lex()
  lexer.input(source_code)
  labels = []
  Ainstr_Address = []
  Ainst_var =[]
  Cinstruction = []
  N_Cinstruction = {
        "dest": "dest" ,
        "cmp" : "cmp" ,
        "jmp" : "jmp" ,
      }
  while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok:
      break
    if tok.type == "LABEL":
      labels.append(tok.value[1:-1])  # Remove Parenthesis from label
      print(tok.value)
    elif tok.type == "AINSTRUCTION":
        Ainstruct = (tok.value.strip("@"))
        print(termcolor.colored("Ains", "green"))
        print(tok.value)
        if  if_address(Ainstruct):
           print(termcolor.colored("Address", "blue"))
           Ainstr_Address.append(tok.value.strip("@"))
        else:
           print(f"the command is {tok.value}")
           Ainst_var.append(tok.value.strip("@"))
    elif tok.type == "CINSTRUCTION":
      print(termcolor.colored("CINSTRUCTION", "magenta"))
      Cinstruction.append(tok.value.strip("\n"))
      print(tok.value)
    elif tok.type == "COMMENTS":
      print(tok.value)
    else:
      continue

  return labels, Ainst_var, Ainstr_Address, Cinstruction
   



source_code =
"""
//n=2
@2
D=M
(loop)
AD=D-1
0;jmp
@ali
MD=1
AMD=!D
@moham
MD=A-1
AMD=D&A
MD=D|A
AMD=M-d
@15
D=m+d
MD=-D
D;JGT
@R1     //using a label
d=m
(example description to the developer)
"""

  



#total labels 3, total vars 3, total Ainst_addre 2, Cinstr 13
LAB, VARS, ADDRESSES, CINSTR = parse_source_code(source_code)
print(LAB)
print(VARS)
print(ADDRESSES)
print(CINSTR)
print(len(CINSTR))


Ah, the classic “I have a problem. I’ll use regular expressions. Now I have two problems!”

Sorry, iPad isn’t being very cooperative. Your regex for the c-instruction looks like it is way too broad in its matching, resulting in the mismatch.  I would suggest making it much more restrictive so it only matches valid c-instructions, and incrementally constructing it so you can confirm it operates properly.

yeah, I thought so too am currently trying to optimize it wish me luck

Start by working up a regexp that handles the destination registers (ie: any combination of A, M and D, at least one, no repeats -- so "A", "AM", "MA", "AMD" and "DMA" are matched, but "" and "AMA" (for example) are not (for this one, I recommend starting with the dumbest possible way of expressing it, even if it is verbose, and then see if you can get fancy). Then you can wrap this inside an optional that ends in =. Then add an expression to handle the ALU operation, and finally an optional that handles the jumps.

Finally, if the regexes prove to be too much of a pain, consider just parsing the lines  directly. The format is simple and it's easy to break up into the subcomponents. This is the approach I took when I wrote my own HACK assembler.

I'd suggest avoiding regular expressions altogether, and doing it the old-fashioned way.  If you see an @ then it is a A-type instruction, and you can parse the number or label that follows.  Otherwise, if you see a ( then process the text as label definition.  Otherwise, ...

Yes, and the Python .split() function makes the parsing very straightforward. You can split on a delimeter and if the resulting list has 2 elements, you know the delimiter was there, and if it has only one, it wasn't. Any other length result is an error.
